# SQL Query: How to improve?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-division

I have two tables in a MySQL database:

```
Book(title, publisher, year) title is primary key

Author(name, title) title is foreign key to Book
```

I am trying to select the name of the Authors that published a book each year from 2000 to 2005 inclusive. This SQL query works, but is there a way to do this that makes it easier to change the date range if needed?

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM Author
WHERE name IN  (SELECT Author.name 
                FROM Author INNER JOIN Book ON (Author.title = Book.title) 
                WHERE year = 2000)
        AND name IN
                (SELECT Author.name 
                FROM Author INNER JOIN Book ON (Author.title = Book.title)
                WHERE year = 2001)
        AND name IN
                (SELECT Author.name 
                FROM Author INNER JOIN Book ON (Author.title = Book.title)
                WHERE year = 2002)
        AND name IN
                (SELECT Author.name 
                FROM Author INNER JOIN Book ON (Author.title = Book.title)
                WHERE year = 2003)
        AND name IN
                (SELECT Author.name 
                FROM Author INNER JOIN Book ON (Author.title = Book.title)
                WHERE year = 2004)
        AND name IN
                (SELECT Author.name 
                FROM Author INNER JOIN Book ON (Author.title = Book.title)
                WHERE year = 2005);
```

Comment: What SQL Database Engine are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? SQLLite?

Comment: Does it have to be exactly 1 book each year, or can it be multiple books some years?

Comment: Sorry, using MySQL. To clarify, I am looking for an Author that published at least 1 book (can be more than 1) *every* year from 2000-2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two ways to do it, and how another approach is wrong due to a subtle fault.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa444f/2)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
create table Book (title varchar(10), year int) ;
create table Author (name varchar(10), title varchar(10));

insert Book values 
('Book1',2000),('Book2',2000),
('Book3',2000),('Book4',2000),
('Book5',2000),('Book6',2000),
('Book7',2001),('Book8',2002),
('Book9',2003),('Book10',2004),
('Book11',2005);

insert into Author values 
('Author1','Book1'),('Author1','Book2'),
('Author1','Book3'),('Author1','Book4'),
('Author1','Book5'),('Author1','Book6'),
('Author2','Book6'),('Author2','Book7'),
('Author2','Book8'),('Author2','Book9'),
('Author2','Book10'),('Author2','Book11');

# author1 has written 6 books in one year
# author2 has written 1 book in every of the six years
```

**Query 1**:

```
# incorrect as it matches author1 who has 6 books in a single year
SELECT name from Author 
INNER JOIN BOOK on Author.title = Book.Title 
WHERE year IN (2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005) 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING COUNT(name) = 6
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa444f/2/0)**:

```
|    NAME |
|---------|
| Author1 |
| Author2 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
# correct as it counts distinct years
SELECT name from Author 
INNER JOIN BOOK on Author.title = Book.Title 
WHERE year IN (2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005) 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT year) = 6
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa444f/2/1)**:

```
|    NAME |
|---------|
| Author2 |
```

**Query 3**:

```
# correct using relational division
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM Author A1
INNER JOIN Book B1 ON A1.title = B1.Title
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Book B2
    WHERE year IN (2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005) 
    AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT *
       FROM Author A2
       INNER JOIN Book B3 ON A2.title = B3.Title
       WHERE (A1.name = A2.name)
        AND (B3.year = B2.year)
    )
)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa444f/2/2)**:

```
|    NAME |
|---------|
| Author2 |
```

Comment: Using COUNT(DISTINCT year) in the Having clause worked with my data. Thank you for pointing out the subtle fault.

Answer (score 0):

I would put an 'OR' clause in the where statement. It depends on how your table is set up but it should work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM Author
     WHERE name IN  (SELECT Author.name 
                     FROM Author INNER JOIN Book ON (Author.title = Book.title) 
                     WHERE year = 2000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, I didn't test it but you can group by and select only the ones that would have 6 rows:

```
SELECT a.name FROM Author a
INNER JOIN Book b
   ON a.title = b.title
WHERE b.year BETWEEN 2000 AND 2005
 GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(a.name) = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use arguments

```
declare @StartYear int = 2000
declare @EndYear int = 2005

select a.name 
from author a
inner join book b on a.title = b.title
where year between @StartDate and @EndDate 
group by a.name
having count(distinct year) = @EndDate- @StartDate
```

It's easy to modify and modify itself whenever year you input